# Secure password store for Python CGI (Windows+IIS+Windows authentification)

Tags: python, environment-variables, python-keyring

I need to develope a python cgi script for a server run on Windows+IIS. The cgi script is run from a web page with Windows authentification. It means the script is run under different users from Windows active directory.

I need to use login/passwords in the script and see no idea how to store the passwords securely, because keyring stores data for a certain user only. Is there a way how to access password data from keyring for all active OS users?

I also tried to use os.environ variables, but they are stored for one web session only.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of here is to run your script as a service account (generic AD account that is used just for this service) instead of using windows authentication. Then you can log into the server as that service account and setup the Microsoft Credential Manager credentials that way.